# How create a folder on SdCard and how to see the same folder on emulator?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have created two string one with the name SDCARD which means "sdcard" and RECYCLE_BIN_ROOT which stands for a folder with name of Recycle in Sdcard. But i am getting problem with this.
I have created code for copying files from sdcard ( for eg images in DICM ) to recycle bin, but   result is zero.I have created recycle folder using file explorer option in eclipse also.
Please tell me some solution.

```
public class C 
{

    public static String SDCARD = "/sdcard";
    public static String RECYCLE_BIN_ROOT = SDCARD+"/.Recycle";
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by result is zero.  Please share the code you are using to copy the files from the sdcard to the recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

```java
java.io.File f = new java.io.File(RECYCLE_BIN_ROOT);
if (!f.exists()) {
     if (f.mkDirs()) {
          Log.v("", "File created successfully...");
     } else {
          Log.v("", "File cannot created successfully...");
          // You can throw exception
     }
}
```